# Send Date From jsp To Controller

Tags: spring, date, jsp

**A.JSP**

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/publish/date/post/${post.postId}">
    <input type="date" name="pDate">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>  
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/publish/date/post/{postId}")
public ModelAndView setPublishDatePostP(@PathVariable Integer postId, 
                                        @RequestParam("pDate") Date topublishDate,
                                        BindingResult result,
                                        HttpServletRequest request,  
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        HttpSession session) {
    ModelAndView mView = new ModelAndView("test");
    Date d = pDate;
    mView.addObject("d", d);
    return mView;
}
```

It show the error

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqkyS.jpg)

> Any one know How to **pass date from Jsp to Controller**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, add a customized date formatter in your controller.

```
@InitBinder
public void intDate(WebDataBinder dataBinder){
    dataBinder.addCustomFormatter(new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}

@PostMapping("/test")
public String test(@RequestParam("date") Date date) {
    return date.toString();
}
```